# Octave structure within a structure

Tags: data-structures, struct, structure, octave

I want to create a structure within a structure in Octave. It looks like

```
class =
    {
        grade = Graduate
        studentname = John
        university =  St. Jones
        student=
             {
                 name=John
                 age=18
                 address=Houston
             }

   }
```

To implement this structure within a structure I write down

```
>> class.grade='graduate';
>> class.studentname='John';
>> class.university='St.Jones';

>> student.name='John';
>> student.age=18;
>> student.address='Houston';

>>student.class=struct %To create structure within a structure
```

I got this output:

```
student =

scalar structure containing the fields:

name = John
age =  18
address = Houstan
class =

  scalar structure containing the fields:
```

I cannot understand why the class structure is empty here? Same is true if I try to run this code like that

```
>> class.student=struct
```

The output is

```
class =

  scalar structure containing the fields:

grade = graduate
studentname = John
university = St.Jones
student =

  scalar structure containing the fields:
```

Please help me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, there are two possibilities from my point of view.

Either set up your (sub)structure `student`, and later set `class.student = student`. By that, the field `student` in `class` is implicitly made a (sub)structure. Code would be like that:

```matlab
class.grade = 'graduate';
class.studentname = 'John';
class.university = 'St.Jones';

student.name = 'John';
student.age = 18;
student.address = 'Houston';

class.student = student

        class =

          scalar structure containing the fields:

            grade = graduate
            studentname = John
            university = St.Jones
            student =

              scalar structure containing the fields:

                name = John
                age =  18
                address = Houston
```

Or you could just use nested structures in the beginning, like so:

```matlab
class.grade = 'graduate';
class.studentname = 'John';
class.university = 'St.Jones';

class.student.name = 'John';
class.student.age = 18;
class.student.address = 'Houston';

class

        class =

          scalar structure containing the fields:

            grade = graduate
            studentname = John
            university = St.Jones
            student =

              scalar structure containing the fields:

                name = John
                age =  18
                address = Houston
```

Again, the field `student` in `class` is implictly made a (sub)structure as well.

Hope that helps!